# Questions that lack enough information

Tags: discussion, question-quality

New today:

[What number comes next?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69357/what-number-comes-next)

The entire question (including title) is:

> What number comes next?
>
> **3, 1, 4, 8, 8, 23, 23, 66, 136, 202, 458, 885, ?**
>   Find the number that comes next.

We have been told nothing. This could be anything from mathematical to the number of partridges in a pear tree to what colour socks am I wearing, reducing the problem to mind-reading the OP.

The sequence is not credited, and home-grown efforts often suck!

On other SE sites this question would be closed and deleted without question.

Should we have a set of guidelines as to the minimal requirements for a question so we can refer this level of question to them?

Comment: You might want to look at [Number-Sequence Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do?rq=1).