# Continuously updating a puzzle

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

I have a number sequence puzzle in mind and I'm so far unsure how many numbers to post. I'll figure something out, but I had also considered just letting my Raspberry Pi update the question every hour or so, adding one more number to it every time. That would add a dynamic speciality to the post and solve the question of how many numbers to provide. But it would also mean that the post would get bumped to the homepage every hour.

I'll probably not do this, but if I did, would it be seen as unfair attention grabbing? Would that be ok, discouraged or disallowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is that a puzzle should be able to be solved as originally posted.  People will sometimes add hints to a puzzle after a certain amount of time if no one seems able to solve it, but all the necessary information to solve it should be present when the puzzle is originally posted.

You might want to look at both answers to [Number-Sequence Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do) before posting a number-sequence puzzle.  Those might help you to determine what is an appropriate number of elements to post to begin with.

If you do find the need to extend your sequence (because no one is able to solve it), I would suggest that it be on the order of days instead of hours.  Automatically updating a question every hour (although it's a neat idea) seems excessive.

Comment: Time zones are one more thing to take into account.